# Navigation Drawer not Starting from top position

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I am working with navigation drawer , There are 12 items and it is working well .when I open navigation drawer then it is shows from 3rd item on top my profile picture is on the top which is not showing. I want to start it from the top. where is my profile picture. I have used `mDrawerList.setSelection(0); but it is starting with 3rd item and suddenly going to top . please help me to solve the problem.

My XML Code below.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/color_primary_green_header"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

        <!-- The main content view -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/nav_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/profileBox"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@null" />
```

```
  public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(0);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            // Log.d(TAG, "onDrawerClosed: " + getTitle());
            Log.e("TKB", " Nav Drawer is closed");
            mDrawerList.setSelection(0);
            //invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
```

Comment: My xml code added please help me  @keshav

Comment: Please add your Java Code because which item should be default it only declared on the Java u have used here is a good example [LINK](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer)

Comment: @w3officefb need your adapter java code to find out whats happening to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use smoothScroll for select the index of navigation drawer.